# Comando não redirecionando

Tags: javascript

Estou colocando um comando dentro de um script para que quando o Usuário apertar o botão "submit", seja gravado determinado dado no banco de dados e logo após isso acontecer um redirecionamento da página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cadAlterar (){
        <?php 
              $idComp = (@$_POST['id']);  

              $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alterar(idComp) VALUES ('$idComp')");

            ?>
         location.href="altCompras.php";

    }
    </script>
```

Salva certinho o dado no Banco de Dados, mas em contrapartida não ha redirecionamento.

Comment: Tente `header('Location:altCompras.php');` veja se atende ao problema do redirecionamento. Lembrando que isso deve ser colocado logo abaixo do `insert` do php.

Comment: Tentei isso, mas também não funcionou

Comment: Tem aqui tudo sobre redirects em PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: como que "salva certinho" se está misturando função javascript com php.?

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou o redirect dentro de uma função, mas não executou ela.

Você tem algumas opções:

#### 1 - Colocar fora da função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
        $idComp = (@$_POST['id']);  
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alterar(idComp) VALUES ('$idComp')");
    ?>
    document.location.href="altCompras.php";
</script>
```

#### 2 Colocar dentro da função e executa-la (redundante)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cadAlterar (){
    <?php 
        $idComp = (@$_POST['id']);  
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alterar(idComp) VALUES ('$idComp')");
    ?>
    document.location.href="altCompras.php";
}

    cadAlterar();
</script>
```

#### 3 - Utilizar o Header do php

```
<?php 
    $idComp = (@$_POST['id']);  
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alterar(idComp) VALUES ('$idComp')");   
    header("Location:altCompras.php");
?>
```